Using an OWL Reasoner to infer individuals of an OWL Class Expression
I am interesting in using an OWL reasoner (e.g. Hermit) to return OWL Individuals beloning to an OWL Class Expression.
To this end, I have been searching for a tool that can be used from a command line (ideally).
I went through the documentation of Apache Jena (see inference support)and open an issue (see github issue). I also went through the documentation of Hermit

Pellet and HermiT do have some kind of CLI, but afaik there is no such command to take i) an ontology and ii) a class expression in e.g. Manchester Syntax to get all instances of it. Indeed, that would only need a few lines of Java code to make a runnable JAR containing such a commandline tool I think. An example how to get instances of a given class by means of an OWL reasoner in OWL API is shown here: https://github.com/Galigator/openllet/blob/integration/examples/src/main/java/openllet/examples/IndividualsExample.java

Indeed, for a class expressions that does need one more step in parsing an OWLClassExpression object from a string taken from an input stream. the class to use here is  https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/util/mansyntax/ManchesterOWLSyntaxParser.html#parseClassExpression-java.lang.String-
